# Validation on dynamic table using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

My form creates n number of rows, each row having 4 columns. Columns contains text fields and selectbox. Each elements should have to validate. I'm using jquery validatio. When I submit the button input field should be validate if there is no value on it.

```
 <tbody>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Add.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@(i + 1)</td>
            <td>
                @*@Html.DropDownList("MatlId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Add[i].MatlId, new SelectList(ViewBag.MatlId, "Id", "Name"), "----Select Material----", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Add[i].Product, new {@id="txtQuantity", @class = "form-control" })
                <span id="errmsg"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Add[i].Remarks, new { @id="txtRemark", @class = "form-control" })
                <span id="errRemark"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</tbody>
```

Validations jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#txtQuantity').on('input', function () {

        var username = $(this).val();
        if (username.length < 1) {
            $("#errmsg").text('Field is required').show();
        }
        else {
            $("#errmsg").hide();
            var expNum = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/);
            if (!expNum.test(username)) {
                $("#errmsg").text('must have number').show();
            } else {
                $("#errmsg").hide();

            }

        }
        //alert(username);
    });

    $('#txtRemark').on('input', function () {

        var username = $(this).val();
        if (username.length < 1) {
            $("#errRemark").text('Enter Description').show()
            //$("#txtQuantity").css("border-bottom", "2px solid #F90A0A"); 
        }
        else {
            $("#errRemark").hide();

        }
        //alert(username);
    });
});
```

It validates first row only, if I validate second row the error message is displaying on first row itself and some times that also does not happen.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please click `<>` and post rendered HTML and JS only. The question is NOT related to your template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IDs need to be UNIQUE - so `<span id="errmsg@(i + 1)">` and  `<span id="errRemark@(i + 1)">`
2. No need to use the IDs anyway. Make them ALL class instead

```js
var expNum = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/);
$(function () {

    $('.txtQuantity').on('input', function () {
        var $errmsg = $(this).closest("tr").find(".errmsg");
        $errmsg.hide();
        var username = $(this).val();
        if (username.length < 1) {
            $errmsg.text('Field is required').show();
        }
        else {
            if (!expNum.test(username)) {
                $errmsg.text('must have number').show();
            }
        }
    });

    $('.txtRemark').on('input', function () {
        var $errRemark = $(this).closest("tr").find(".errRemark");
        $errRemark").hide();
        var username = $(this).val();
        if (username.length < 1) {
            $errRemark.text('Enter Description').show()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,clear informsation works perfectly.It works for dropdown list too **@mplungjan**

Comment: i have 5 default row,i had entered two rows of values and click the save button,but all field row and null rows are stored in database.                    
 how to save only filled valued row?

Comment: I would need to see the actual [mcve] - can you create a new question with only HTML and Script?

Comment: If you use AJAX, you can try to serialize the form values

Comment: You might need to add change: `on("change, input"`